# Communication between 192.168.0.X and 10.146.1.X

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, printer

So... I wish I understood this and am open to being taught to fish in addition to a solution to my specific problem... but at the moment I would just love to be able to access my printer. :( I'd appreciate some help.

I have a TP-Link router R (192.168.0.1) that connects to the modem/firewall and the internet. Computer A is plugged directly into that router. I also have a Linksys Velop wireless router W that is plugged into router R, and a network printer P that connects wirelessly to W, as well as Laptop computer B that connects wirelessly to W.

With everything configured by default, everything connected to R was getting IP addresses via DHCP in the 192.168.0.X range. And everything connected to W was getting IP addresses in the 192.168.1.X range. But computer A could not print to printer P.

I found this answer ([Communication possible between 192.168.0.x and 192.168.1.x?](https://superuser.com/questions/712256/communication-possible-between-192-168-0-x-and-192-168-1-x)) and thought, "AHA! I just have to change the subnet mask of R to 255.255.240.0. That'll magically work."

If you're reading this far, I'm sure you realize that it didn't work.

After I rebooted everything, now:

- R is 192.168.0.1, subnet mask is 255.255.240.0
- A received 192.168.0.103 from R via DHCP
- W is now reporting IP address 10.146.1.1, subnet mask 255.255.255.0
  (WTF?)
- P is 10.146.1.80
- B is 10.146.1.87

B can print to P and reach out to the internet.

A still can't print but obviously can reach out to the internet

So... where did I go wrong here? And most importantly, how can I get A to print to P?

Comment: Reconfigure the Wifi router as an AP. To do this disable DHCP (and optionally change its IP address to 192.168.0.253 assuming that IP address is not part if the DHCP pool) and plug the main router into the LAN, not WAN port.  You will then have everything in the 192.168.0 network and no routing conplexities.

Comment: What were the problems? I wonder if they will be easier to solve then your routing problems.

Comment: Thank you! I tried your suggestion but no luck: (1) I tried to disable DHCP and give the wireless router a static IP in the 192.168.0.x range, but when the router rebooted and the laptop and printer reconnected, they still report getting IP addresses from it in the 10.x.x.x range. Wifi router is administered remotely via the Linksys Velop app on a phone, so I may not be able to configure it as needed. (2) I'm not clear on what you mean by "plug the main router into the LAN." Router R is needed to connect house Cat6 ports to the cable modem. This diagram may help: https://imgur.com/a/XIRnWZz

Comment: You have done something wrong in your config change - but ai cant tell what.  I can confirm that routers have at least a WAN and LAN interface. For the setup above there needs to be nothing connected to the WAN interface on router W - you need to move.the canle plugged into  the WAN interface into a LAN port.

Answer (score 0):

In order to fix your routing as it stands you need to get a static IP address on WAN interface on W - either by a DHCP assignment controlled by R or by manually assigning it an address in the 192.168.0 range (but outside the DHCP range). You then need to add a static route for 10.0.0.0 netmask 255.0.0.0 via the new IP adress on router R.

Depending on the setup of router W you may need to disable NAT on it.

Lastly you will need to manually add the IP address of the printer to devices directly connected to R as they are not in the same subnet as the printer and will not be autodiscovered.

Comment: Thanks, I'll see what I can do.

Comment: Well, thanks for your help. I guess I just don't understand how to map your advice to the user interface of the two routers. I guess I'll have to find someone to hire, I just can't make sense of it. Thanks anyway.